# Software Development Analysis

Tags: design-patterns

What do you think of Mr. King's software development analyst at http://devadept.com/?

I ask because reading his blog has made me rethink how I should be coding software.  I mean, I used to concern myself with just getting a project done, but I think I may be missing something and his blog makes me feel that way.

Am I just a programmer "playing" software architect?  I don't know, but one thing is for sure, and that is his blog has made me want to become a better coder and architect.

Comment: Subjective, not a real question, should be wiki, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A ha!!!!  He finally started blogging again.  I thought it was cool how Ivan caught a bug on one of his posts and he graciously thanked him and called him his pair from 10,000 kilometers away.  This guy, Eric King, is not only a good developer, but he has a seriuosly interesting sense of humor.  Sounds like a cool guy -- I need a pair like that  - we have people at my job who make [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) daily!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's the purpose of the blog, to make you feel inadequate so that you'll want to get better.  I know that's the effect it has on me.

Based on what little I've seen of his website, he seems to have the right sensibility, which is to use tools to simplify, not complicate.

He has quite the mug shot, too.

Comment: I agree about the mugshot; a kind of messianic benevolent gaze...

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting read, but the most striking part to me was the link out for the concept of "Technical Debt". This is most intriguing.

He has good way of presenting tips and citing references as a part of the walk-through of how he solved (or came across) problems.